# How to find those users whose preferences are a superset of a given set preference_list?

Tags: python, database, django, filter, django-orm

this is a problem I've been pondering for a while, and I would want to hear opinions from more experienced Django developers than me. Say, I have the following models:

```
class Preference(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    preferences = models.ManyToManyField(Preference, blank=True)
```

The preferences could be related to food, for example. I like beef and potatoes so they would be my preferences.

What is the most efficient way to find users who have at least beef AND potatoes in their preferences, for example? So, I want to find a user that could have ice cream and salad in their preferences in addition to beef and potatoes.

Option 1 (iteration):

```
query = UserProfile.objects.all()   # all user objects

for p in preference_list:           # preference_list contains beef and potatoes
     query = query.filter(preferences__in==p.id)
```

Option 2 (DB, pseudocode):

```
SELECT * from UserProfile WHERE preferences is a superset of preference_list
```

I think the option 2 would be more efficient but I have no idea how to implement it in Django. Any advice or opinions how to lay out the models for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a first filter to keep preferences in the set only, then make sure you have all preferences in the set using `Count`:

```
preferences = ('beef', 'potatoes')
UserProfile.objects.filter(preferences__name__in=preferences
    ).annotate(pref_count=models.Count('preferences')
    ).filter(pref_count=len(preferences)
```

This could indeed be more efficient, as it will not add a join for each preference searched for (pseudocode too):

```
SELECT * FROM userprofile
  LEFT OUTER JOIN userprofile_preferences
  LEFT OUTER JOIN preference
  WHERE preference IN (beef, potato)
  GROUP BY userprofile
  HAVING COUNT(userprofile_preferences) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your solution seems to be working also in practice.

Could it be possible to create a container class PreferenceSet that contains Preference objects and then compare PreferenceSet objects of the users? Is there some kind of superset or subset method in Django that would allow such comparisons between these PreferenceSet objects?